# My video wont stop playing when i stop hovering on the thumb nail

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I tried making a thumbnail to play a YouTube video when I hover and stop playing when I stop hovering on it, but it doesn't stop when the mouse isn't hovering on it.
Here's the code:

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-video-id="D9N7QaIOkG8">
    <img src="assets\meyra.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1">
    <div class="video-overlay"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

    thumbnails.forEach(function(thumbnail) {
      const videoOverlay = thumbnail.querySelector(".video-overlay");
      const videoId = thumbnail.dataset.videoId;

      thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        const player = new YT.Player(videoOverlay, {
          videoId: videoId,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 0,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0
          }
        });

        videoOverlay.style.display = "block";
      });

      thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        videoOverlay.innerHTML = "";
        videoOverlay.style.display = "none";
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want the YT video to stop playing when I stop hovering on the thumbnail

Comment: Have you tried logging messages to the console in both the **mouseenter()** and **mouseleave()** functions to see if they’re actually being run?

Comment: Hello, I don't see any instruction telling your code to stop the "player", you are only setting the css "display" property to "none", but this does not mean to stop the video

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: Read my answer. Anyway, you should not recreate a new object on every `mouseenter` event. It does not make sense... Instead, show that after hiding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @sohaieb azaiez, you are not stopping the player. Insert this line in in the listener for `mouseleave`:

```js
player.pauseVideo()
```

The whole function should be:

```js
thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  player.pauseVideo()
  videoOverlay.innerHTML = "";
  videoOverlay.style.display = "none";
  });
```

Please read the [YouTube Player API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Functions), there are many other methods and working examples.